# how to disable application restart on hitting actuator/refresh/

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-actuator

i have 2 submodules->config-server and config-client .everything is working fine.To reflect any changes made in git remote repo->.properties file i have to invoke http://client-server.port/actuator/refresh/  .After hitting this api i get updated property values in client but it restarts my client application.How to avoid application-restart? Also can i make config-server to directly update property values in client classes whenever any git remote repo properties are changed?

Answer (score 1):

Console logs were printing misleading logs.
Only those classes which have @RefreshScope Annotation reloads